# 11.exe has stopped working (Code Blocks)

Tags: c

It is a simple program to find trace of a square matrix but whenever i try to run the code error pops up "11.exe has stopped working".

I have windows 8.1

I'm using GNU GCC compiler.
here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n,i,j,a[n][n],tr=0;
    printf("enter order of square matrix\n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("enter the entries of matrix\n");
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("a[%d][%d]",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
        tr+=a[i][i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)

        {
            printf("%d",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("trace of matrix is\t%d",tr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use the debugger. Set breakpoints.

Comment: ...or just spend 30 seconds looking at your own code. Code like `int x; printf("%d", x); scanf("%d",&x); // read 5 from user` won't print the value 5, but rather print garbage or crash & burn, because code lines are executed in the order you type them...

Answer (score 4):

In your code

```
a[n][n]
```

invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). as you've used `n`'s. value uninitialized. That's certainly not how you use [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

For reference, from `C11` standard document

**Point 1.** Chapter `6.7.9`, paragraph 10,

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate.

***....[The case for `int n`, `n` is not initialized explicitly]***

and

**Point 2.**

from the Annex J, chapter `J.2`, reasons for undefined behaviour,

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate.

***....[The case of `a[n][n],`]***

**Solution:**

You need to move the definition of `a` after you have successfully *scanned* the value of `n`.

Answer (score 1):

```
 int n,i,j,a[n][n],tr=0;
 printf("enter order of square matrix\n");
 scanf("%d",&n);
```

should be

```
int n,i,j,tr=0;
printf("enter order of square matrix\n");
scanf("%d",&n);
int a[n][n];
```

Now `a` is a variable length array(VLA). VLA is supported from C99 .

The reason for your problem is already explained by **@Sourav**